# Как исключить из списка определенный текст?

Tags: python, excel, csv, ms-word, robots.txt

Дано 9000 url ссылок в формате CSV либо txt (есть и тот и тот). Есть еще один список url ссылок (300 шт). Задача из первого списка  исключить второй при том, что все ссылки в первом списке в хаотичном порядке. Нужно процесс автоматизировать. Мб кто-то сталкивался с подобным, сам голову ломаю. Еще ищу прогу которая из списка ссылок сделает HTML документ сайта. Мне нужно минимум  мануального ввода, ибо надо бысто работать. Спасибо за ответы ！

Comment: приведите небольшой пример данных (3-5 строк) в формате CSV

Answer (score 1):

Возвращает разность множеств A и B (элементы, входящие в A, но не входящие в B).

```
A = {"url1", "url2", "url4", "url5", "url9"}

B = {"url2", "url6", "url7", "url9"}

A.difference(B)
{'url4', 'url1', 'url5'}
```

или

```
A-B
{'url4', 'url1', 'url5'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = set(['www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler','http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.phpv'])
b = set(['https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0','http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php','http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php'])


print(a|b)
```